# Is there a .get() in angular firestore?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs, angularfire2

I have seen there is a .valueChanges() and .snapshotChanges() which both listen to changes in the database but what if I want to retrieve the data just once?
I noticed that adding .pipe(take(1)) at the end of .valueChanges() or .snapshotChanges() works but is it the same as .get() function that firebase firestore provides in admin sdk and mobile sdk for Android and iOS?

What I'm doing

```
 this.items = this.itemCollection.valueChanges().pipe(take(1));
```

What I'm expecting

```
 this.items = this.itemCollection.get();
```

PS: I'm new to react.

Comment: That `get()` call seems to exist as far as I can see: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/705505a1806ae02d5bb08d3fc0d6ca24d9635527/src/firestore/collection/collection.ts#L129. What is the problem when you run this code?

Comment: Could you point me to any documentation for it? How to use it to retrieve a list of documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Non-React way

If you are looking for a way to do it without using react, you can call the get() method on the ref instead of the collection item.

```
this.itemCollection.ref.get().then((querySnap) => {
     //use your data here
     console.log(querySnap.docs);
});
```

## The React way

this.itemCollection.get() returns an observable of type QuerySnapshot that you can subscribe to

```
this.itemCollection.get().subscribe((querySnap) => {
 console.log(querySnap.docs)
});
```